# How to prove this statement about the Fibonacci Sequence using induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I need to show that for the terms of the fibonnaci sequence, where $n \ge 1$, $a_{n-1} \times a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + (-1)^n$

And the formula to calculate fibonacci numbers where $n \ge 1$ is $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

I've tried subbing in just about everything starting with the left side, then I tried the right side. I can't get it to work through induction. Which side should I start with? And what should I be substituting to make it equal to the otherside?

Comment: My bad, yeah it's supposed to be n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After covering any base cases, you can do the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n-1} \color{blue}{a_{n+1}}
&=& a_{n-1}\color{blue}{(a_n+a_{n-1})} \tag{by definition of $a_{n+1}$}\\
&=& a_{n} a_{n-1} + \color{red}{a_{n-1}^2}\tag{distributing $a_{n-1}$}\\
&=& a_{n} a_{n-1} + \color{red}{a_{n-2} a_n - (-1)^{n-1}} \tag{induction hypothesis}\\
&=& a_n\color{blue}{(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})} - (-1)^{n-1} \tag{factoring out $a_n$}\\
&=& a_n \color{blue}{a_n} - (-1)^{n-1} \tag{by definition of $a_n$}\\
&=& a_n^2 + (-1)^n
\end{eqnarray}